# How to set attribute (JSXAttr) in SWC plugin using rust

Tags: rust, swc-compiler

I need to set attributes on elements.

```
fn visit_mut_jsx_opening_element(&mut self, n: &mut JSXOpeningElement){

}
```

JSXOpeningElement finds all opening elements

Please see its content - https://rustdoc.swc.rs/swc_ecma_ast/struct.JSXOpeningElement.html

Fragment from the documentation:

```
pub struct JSXOpeningElement {
    pub name: JSXElementName,
    pub span: Span,
    pub attrs: Vec<JSXAttrOrSpread>,
    pub self_closing: bool,
    pub type_args: Option<Box<TsTypeParamInstantiation>>,
}
```

I see that to add an attribute you need to set  ***n.attrs***.

Type: vector with type JSXAttrOrSpread

```
fn visit_mut_jsx_opening_element(&mut self, n: &mut JSXOpeningElement){
     n.attrs = vec![];
}
```

**It works! I'm removing the attributes because I'm passing in an empty vector.**

But I need to create an attribute. Everything I pass to the vector causes an error

JSXAttrOrSpread documentation - https://rustdoc.swc.rs/swc_ecma_ast/enum.JSXAttrOrSpread.html

JSXAttr documentation - https://rustdoc.swc.rs/swc_ecma_ast/struct.JSXAttr.html

I tried like this:

1.

```
fn visit_mut_jsx_opening_element(&mut self, n: &mut JSXOpeningElement){
     n.attrs = vec![JSXAttr(Ident::new("className".into(), n.span).into())];
}
// error - error[E0277]: the trait bound `swc_core::ecma::ast::JSXAttr: From<swc_core::ecma::ast::Ident>` is not satisfied
```

2. 

```
fn visit_mut_jsx_opening_element(&mut self, n: &mut JSXOpeningElement){
     n.attrs = vec![JSXAttr("className".into())];
}
// error[E0277]: the trait bound `swc_core::ecma::ast::JSXAttr: From<&str>` is not satisfied
```

3. 

```
fn visit_mut_jsx_opening_element(&mut self, n: &mut JSXOpeningElement){
     n.attrs = vec![JSXAttr(JSXAttrName::Ident(Ident::new("className".into(),n.span).into()))];
}
// expected struct `JSXAttr`, found enum `JSXAttrName`
```

Help me please. I'm in pain for days

I am using the latest version of rust, swc, cargo